# Stop DataContractSerializer putting in namespace?

Tags: datacontractserializer, datacontract

I want to serialize datacontract classes into XMl, but without the Namespaces.

I've added:

```
[DataContract(Namespace="")]
```

but I still get:

```
<Person xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Title>Mr</Title>
...
</Person>
```

Is there any way to stop this happening as I just want the clean xml to pass into a legacy component.